# Can I auto upload images from the directory using Flask or anything else?

Tags: python, flask

Hello I'm new to python I'm finding a method to auto upload images to a webserver. Someone can help me?
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: To what *webserver* are you wanting to upload said images?

Comment: webserver on raspberry pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Flask command-line Interface and create a method to upload files by reading a directory and if you need recurrent can use CRON task from the OS to auto-execute come times in the day also you can use this method may be called from a web interface as well:

[Flask Command Line Interface](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/cli/#command-line-interface)